# Find equation of a 3d curved surface defined by two 2D cubic equations

Tags: 3d, parametrization

I have compiled data and identified best fit quadratic equations ($R^2>99$%) in the $XZ$ and $YZ$ spaces like so:

$z = 0.0000004x^2 - 0.0035x + 26.588$

...where $y = 358.242$

$z = 0.0002y^2 - 0.207y + 62.77$

...where $x = 3750$

My assumption is that these two equations para-metrically define curves that are slices out of a 3D surface in perpendicular planes. I would like to do some analysis of this 3D surface (in actuality there are multiple of these surfaces that will interact with each other, but I don't want to complicate the question).

> The question is: how can I take these two equations and turn them into a single equation (in terms of $X$ and $Y$) that defines a 3D surface?

Note: I did a search, but I am a civil engineer and it has been a long time since I have had to think about this kind of thing, so I am having trouble seeing which existing questions are most relevant to my problem.

Comment: By analogy, you know what the line of the roof looks like at either end of a very long winding street and you want to know what the roof profile is like all the way along? you would need to make some assumptions about what is going on between the two ends..

Comment: @Paul I guess I have to make an educated guess about the shape of the surface. If I make that guess -- for example, if I assume the surface is a paraboloid -- do I then have enough information to define the equation....?

Comment: @Paul I could collect additional data to define additional slices in the portion of the surface that is of interest, but I am concerned that once I get all that data I'm going to be overwhelmed with how to analyze it. Having an estimated 3D curve seems much more manageable. There is also the problem that collecting that data would take a lot of time.

Comment: If you could find a collection of z values at points of the form (x, 0) and (0, y) you could potentially "slide" some interpolation of your quadratics along that rail of points to make a surface.

Comment: @Paul Sounds possible and I understand it. But when it comes to how to practically do it, I'm left wondering if I am better off trying a different approach to this entire thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your curves cannot be slices of a same 3D surface, with equation $z=f(x,y)$. If we set $x_0=3750$ and $y_0=358.242$, then the equations of these slices should be $z=f(x,y_0)$ and $z=f(x_0,y)$, but this requires that $f(x_0,y_0)$ should have the same value on both slices. In your case this doesn't happen, because substituting $x=x_0$ in the first equation we get $z\approx 19.1$ while substituting $y=y_0$ in the second one we get $z\approx 14.3$.

I think you should instead run your best fit on $z=f(x,y)$, taking into account both sets of data.

Comment: This seems so obvious now that you have pointed it out; it stands to reason two parametric best fit curves won't necessarily (probably almost never) coincide with each other and form the boundaries of a surface. I suppose now I have to decide if it is worth the effort of trying to create a best fit surface (I am not sure how to do that).

Comment: FYI: I had a small mistake in the first equation and have fixed it; the numbers are now closer together than before, but still off by enough to be a problem.